# Use Godot game as an Activity or Fragment in a larger Android Studio application

Tags: android, android-activity, game-development, godot

I have been making a game for a while in Android Studio, using just plain Android features like Drawable-s and such for the visuals.

I am planning to add change/update some things and I think that would be easier to do with Godot, but I want to keep the rest of the application in Android Studio.

Is it possible to make something in Godot and export/integrate that into an Android Studio project? Maybe as a separate Activity or Fragment?

If not possible in Godot, is it possible in some other similar game engine?

Comment: it seems to be possible unfortunately there is  no documentation for it 
https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/39558

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha Interesting. Can you add it as an answer so I can accept it as a solution?

Comment: @devil0150  I have done this, check here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rn7iB4XQDmQ&list=PLQhQEGkwKZUobJyaYz2pQz8KWm-Pkv3rp&index=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is indeed possible to do this in Godot ([github discussion](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/42186)), but there is no documentation for it yet ([github discussion](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-docs/issues/4018)).

However I discovered it is possible to run LibGDX code in a fragment of an activity ([wiki page](https://libgdx.com/wiki/app/starter-classes-and-configuration#game-fragment)). I ended up doing it with LibGDX both because I found it to have less of a learning curve from my experience, and it would still be part of the android application and I could pass callbacks and other Java objects back and forth between the Android specific features and LibGDX game logic.